# Remove ubuntu-online-account after an upgrade

Tags: upgrade, evolution, online-accounts

I used Ubuntu 14.04 and had a couple of accounts set up using ubuntu-online-accounts. After upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04, I am not able to remove or edit accounts from uoa, and they are still used by Evolution (with outdated passwords).

Is there a file or directory that holds the uoa accounts that I can remove to get rid of uoa accounts?

Comment: Did you check **Online Accounts** in GNOME **Settings**?

Comment: @fedonKadifeli Yes, I did. GNOME Online Accounts (goa) are different than Ubuntu Online Accounts (uoa). I don't see uoa accounts in goa settings. After upgrade I lost access to uoa settings, but they are still picked up by Evolution. I would like to completely remove uoa from my computer and keep using goa only, but I dont know which files to remove.

Answer (score 0):

This is/was driving me crazy as well, I couldn't get rid of the uoa accounts in Evolution and the popups asking for the passwords.

Finally I found some files in my Evolution settings where account or other data sources are defined:
Path: ~/.config/evolution/sources

some files did contain account information like this example:

```
[Data Source]
DisplayName=yahoo (*<login>*)
Enabled=true
Parent=

[Ubuntu Online Accounts]
AccountId=0

[Collection]
BackendName=yahoo
...
```

After changing the all the "Enabled=true" lines to "Enabled=false" the popups stopped appearing even though the accounts were still visible in Evolution account settings. After removing the files the account information did disappear completely.

Of course I tried several other things before and maybe some of them did play a part as well so here is a few more things I tried before.
Checked and edited the following files:

```
~/.config/signond/signon.db 
~/.config/libaccounts-glib/accounts.db 
~/.config/goa-1.0/accounts.conf (as the name suggests this is probably used for GOA accounts only)
Did cleanup up a plethora of obsolete packages from previous ubuntu versions.
```

Hope this helps